# Flash NetConnection Problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, netconnection

I wrote an flash actionscript 3.0 movie that needs to use netconnection and netstream for streaming. When I test the movie through flash ide the movie connects alright.But when I insert the swf in html and view from firefox, chrome or other browser NetConnection.connect() does not work. Movie sort of hangs at the moment NetConnection.connect is called(). The function assigned to NetStatusEvent is not called and no command after that moment is carried out.

It only occurs when viewed through web browser but when it is tested in flash ide it works alright.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I dont have debug version of flash player. i am getting it now. do you think it can be a server side problem or problem with my local swf file

Comment: Hell, i got the following error when used debugger version of flash player:SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///E:/Program Files/developer/xampp/htdocs/Flash HTML MP3 Recorder/published/Recorder.swf cannot access Internet URL rtmp://127.0.0.1/oflaDemo.
 at flash.net::NetConnection/connect()
 at Recorder_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: +1 for getting the debug version ;)  I've changed my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a local-with-network file to access the internet, which causes a [security sandbox violation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html).

You need to compile your SWF with `-use-network=true` (if you're in Flash Builder or FDT) or alter your export settings in the Flash IDE accordingly.